# How to derive the resonant frequency from the RLC circuit?

Tags: ac, frequency, circuit-analysis

Just like the title, i have an AC circuit (RLC) RL in series and they are in parallel with C.
How do I derive the resonant frequency from that circuit? It says to derive from first principles. I got the resonant frequency for XL=XC but it is not same as the resonant frequency below... **Any help on deriving that resonant frequency?**

Here's the circuit.
[image: AC Circuit]

And here's the resonant frequency which supposed to be the answer.
[image: The Resonant Frequency of AC circuit]

Comment: I think you are asking for the damped resonant frequency.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Find the input admittance
[image]

$$Y = j\omega C + \frac{1}{R+j\omega L} = j\omega C + \frac{R-j\omega L}{R^2+\omega^2 L^2}$$ 
$$Y = \frac{R}{R^2+\omega^2 L^2} + j(\omega C + \frac{-\omega L}{R^2+\omega^2 L^2}) $$

Then the Resonant Fequency is when the Imaginary component of the input admittance is zero$$Im(Y)=0$$

---

So $$\omega C + \frac{-\omega L}{R^2+\omega^2 L^2} = 0$$

$$\omega C = \frac{\omega L}{R^2+\omega^2 L^2} $$

$$\frac{C(R^2+\omega^2 L^2)}{L} =1 $$

$$\frac{R^2C+\omega^2 CL^2}{L} =1 $$

$$\frac{R^2C}{L}+\omega^2 LC =1 $$

$$\omega^2 LC = 1 - \frac{R^2C}{L} $$

I bet you can take it form here